# Modify object whose name is based on contents of an array

Tags: julia

I have a two-element vector whose elements can only be 0 or 1. For the sake of this example, suppose `x = [0, 1]`. Suppose also there are four objects `y00, y01, y10, y11`. My goal is to update the corresponding `y` (`y01` in this example) according to the current value of `x`.

I am aware I can do this using a series of `if` statements:

```
if x == [0, 0]
    y00 += 1
elseif x == [0, 1]
    y01 += 1
elseif x == [1, 0]
    y10 += 1
elseif x == [1, 1]
    y11 += 1
end
```

However, I understand this can be done more succinctly using [Julia's metaprogramming](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/), although I'm unfamiliar with its usage and can't figure out how.
I want to be able to express something like `y{x[1]}{x[2]} += 1` (which is obviously wrong); basically, be able to refer and modify the correct `y` according to the current value of `x`.
So far, I've been able to call the actual *value* of the correct `y` (but I can't summon the `y` object itself) with something like

```
eval(Symbol(string("y", x[1], x[2])))
```

I'm sorry if I did not use the appropriate lingo, but I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Since you know your indices to be two-element vectors, you would definitely be better off (performancewise) using tuples `(i,j)` instead of vectors `[i,j]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a much more elegant way using [`StaticArrays`](https://juliaarrays.github.io/StaticArrays.jl/stable/pages/api/#StaticArrays.FieldMatrix).  You can define a common type for your `y` values, which will behave like a matrix (which I assume the `y`s represent?), and defines a lot of things for you:

```
julia> mutable struct Thing2 <: FieldMatrix{2, 2, Float64}
           y00::Float64
           y01::Float64
           y10::Float64
           y11::Float64
       end

julia> M = rand(Thing2)
2×2 Thing2 with indices SOneTo(2)×SOneTo(2):
 0.695919  0.624941 
 0.404213  0.0317816

julia> M.y00 += 1
1.6959194941562996

julia> M[1, 2] += 1
1.6249412302897646

julia> M * [2, 3]
2-element SArray{Tuple{2},Float64,1,2} with indices SOneTo(2):
 10.266662679181893 
  0.9037708026795666
```

(Side note: Julia indices begin at 1, so it might be more idiomatic to use one-based indices for `y` as well.  Alternatively, [can create](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/offset-arrays/#Writing-custom-array-types-with-non-1-indexing-1) array types with custom indexing, but that's more work, again.)

Comment: Perhaps more to the point for this specific question: `x=(0,1); M[CartesianIndex(x.+1)] += 1`

Answer (score 2):

How about using x as linear indices into an array Y?

```
x = reshape(1:4, 2, 2)
Y = zeros(4);
Y[ x[1,2] ] += 1
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the prompt — and requires a restructuring of what `x` means without really describing it adequately IMO.

Comment: @MattB. I don't see why. OP said themselves that 0 vs 1 was just a suggestion. Julia is 1-based rather than 0-based, so 1 vs 2 makes more sense. And generally, naming variables as y00, y01 instead of using an array is discouraged in any language.

Comment: I'm just saying _I_ didn't understand how you were reframing the example at first.  I just think you need a bit more explanation about how you're changing the prompt and how that reframing solves the underlying desire in the question.  Perhaps the downvote was too harsh, but that's why I thought it was worth adding my own answer.

Comment: @MattB. Yes, fair enough, I saw your answer (+1) right after this comment and figured out that's probably what you meant here. :)  Ach, I don't disagree ... it's just that time and time again here I've found (to my surprise and dissapointment) most people who ask this kind of question don't care for (or read) elaborate explanations, and prefer short snippets that solve their problem. So these days I keep things as terse as possible, and at least try to have non-obfuscated code, in the hope that playing with the provided code will provide the necessary insights in a smaller digestible chunk.

Comment: @MattB. even more depressingly, my experience on the site has shown me that the exact same code condensed to fewer lines has more chances of being read than properly spaced code, even if the condensed version is far uglier. Frustrating, but, what can you do.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you find yourself naming variables with sequential numbers it's a **HUGE RED FLAG** that you should just use an array instead.  No need to make it so complicated with a custom static array or linear indexing — you can just make `y` a plain old 2x2 array.  The straight-forward transformation is:

```
y = zeros(2,2)
if x == [0, 0]
    y[1,1] += 1
elseif x == [0, 1]
    y[1,2] += 1
elseif x == [1, 0]
    y[2,1] += 1
elseif x == [1, 1]
    y[2,2] += 1
end
```

Now you can start seeing a pattern here and simplify this by using `x` as an index directly into `y`:

```
y[(x .+ 1)...] += 1
```

I'm doing two things there: I'm adding one to all the elements of `x` and then I'm *splatting* those elements into the indexing expression so they're treated as a two-dimensional lookup.  From here, you could make this more Julian by just using one-based indices from the get-go and potentially making `x` a `Tuple` or `CartesianIndex` for improved performance.